# mousedown event only works on second click

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a mousedown event that change the image of an object in a canvas. However, during the first click the update function doesn't update the image unless I add a Timeout. Futhermore, I even tried with a promise to wait after the new image link before to call the update function, but I get the same result.

```js
GameButton = new button(140, 50, 'img/GameButton.svg', 190, 460);

MyGame.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
  if((e.clientX - GameRoom.getBoundingClientRect().left) >= GameButton.x && (e.clientX -         GameRoom.getBoundingClientRect().left) <= (GameButton.x + GameButton.width) && (e.clientY - GameRoom.getBoundingClientRect().top) >= GameButton.y && (e.clientY - GameRoom.getBoundingClientRect().top) <= GameButton.y + GameButton.height){
   GameButton.image.src = 'img/GameButtonDown.svg';
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    GameButton.update();
  },3);
});
      
      
function button(width,height,img,x,y){

  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.image = new image();
  this.image.src = img;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  
  this.update = function(){
    ctx = MyGameRoom.ctx;
    ctx.drawImage(this.image,
    this.x,
    this.y,
    this.width, this.height);
  }
}
```

It seems like the update method is triggered before the new image.src

Comment: `this.image` or `this.img`?  We're missing lots of code, so the run code snippet is a total fail.  `console.log(xxxx);` is your friend.  Also, verify JavaScript errors when running program in Chrome browser while using developer tools.

Comment: There's no error and I can't actually give the whole code, I mean there is a ton of code. However, I can reproduce the issue with that code.

Comment: If using text instead of an image for your button - would this work? Also where do you take `this.image` from? from a file? Did you checkes if the image is already loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `update` just draws the image but the image itself is not immediately available after setting `.src`... you need to wait for the loading.
A solution could be adding an event handler for `load` on the image that automatically triggers the update.

```
this.image.onload = (event)=>{
    this.update();
};
```

Comment: It's working! Thanks!

I didn't know I had to wait for the loading.